# Redirecting all requests that aren't from my IP with nginx

Tags: http, redirect, nginx

I want all nginx requests that aren't made by my IP address to be redirected to `/some-page`. I'm currently using this nginx config:

```
    if ($remote_addr != 127.0.0.1) {
        rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/some-page;
    }
```

This works for me as I'm not redirected, but anyone else is stuck in a redirect loop since the block doesn't check if the request is for `/some-page`.

How can I fix this? I'm not sure how to check the request path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this `if` is created inside the `location /` for example, create a separate `location /some-page` this way the `if` won't be executed when the URI is `/some-page`

---

**EDIT**: ok let me explain what i understood and you tell me if i'm right or wrong,

1. Good IP (yours): serve page as it is
2. Bad IP (not yours): redirect to `/some-page`

The problem is, when Bad IP is redirected to `/some-page` it still redirects to `/some-page` again because it's still a Bad IP, so it passes the `if` test

**My solution**: Remove the `/some-page` location from the `/` block:

```
location / {
    # bla bla
    if ($remote_addr != 127.0.0.1) {
        rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/some-page;
    }
    # rest of bla bla
}
location /some-page {
    try_files index.html index.php; # or whatever
}
```

When Bad IP is forwarded to `/some-page` it no longer will execute the `if` condition, so that will end the infinite redirection loop.

---

**Second EDIT**: You could set the permissions in nginx it self, let me demonstrate:

```
location / {
    error_page 403 = @badip
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    #rest of bla bla
}
location @badip {
    return 301 $scheme://example.com/some-page;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand you. I want the check to affect every request in the `server` block. Adding a `location /some-page` doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving the issue by doing another `if` check for the request path. I knew nginx doesn't support nested `if` statements so I searched and found [this blog post](http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2011/05/nginx-rewrite-test-multiple-conditions.html) which provides a workaround -- updating a variable with each statement you want to check and then matching it in a final statement. In my case, I did this, which works:

```
    if ($remote_addr != 127.0.0.1) {
      set $check O;
    }
    if ($request_uri != "/some-page") {
      set $check "${check}K";
    }
    if ($check = OK) {
        rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/some-page;
    }
```